# Cannot get value form JSON object in a sveltekit loop

Tags: arrays, json, object, prismic.io, sveltekit

I am using SvelteKit to pull a Prismic object. If I query a single document, I can render the data out fine. However, if I query everything and try to itemize it out in a loop, I am unable to extract the text value from the object.

Stringifying the object, I can see the data I want:

```
<pre>{ JSON.stringify(results, null, 2) }</pre>
```

allows me to see the data

```
[
  {
    "type": "accounts",
    "data": {
      "created_at": "2021-08-25T05:00:00+0000",
      "name": [
        {
          "type": "heading2",
          "text": "John",
          "spans": []
        }
      ],
      "last_name": [
        {
          "type": "heading2",
          "text": "Doe",
          "spans": []
        }
      ],
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "accounts",
    "data": {
      "created_at": "2021-08-25T05:00:00+0000",
      "name": [
        {
          "type": "heading2",
          "text": "Jane",
          "spans": []
        }
      ],
      "last_name": [
        {
          "type": "heading2",
          "text": "Rey",
          "spans": []
        }
      ],
    }
  },
]
```

I am trying to get the last_name from the loop, ie Doe and Rey

```
{#each results as account}   
  <li>{ account.data.last_name }</li>    
{/each}
```

sends back an object. and

```
{#each results as account}
  <li>{ account.data.last_name.text }</li>
{/each}
```

throws an undefined error. I know it has something to with the name and last_name being in the brackets. I just don't know how to extract those in the loop.

I've tried:

```
account.data.last_name[0]
account.data.last_name["text]
account.data.last_name[0].text
```

and 20 more iterations of that. I feel I am missing something incredibly obvious here.

Answer (score 1):

Just cross-posting my response from the Prismic forum :)

https://community.prismic.io/t/cannot-get-value-form-json-object-in-a-sveltekit-loop/6765/3?u=samlittlefair

Comment: Added my response on that forum. If we get to an answer, I'll update SO so anyone with the same problem knows the solution.

Comment: Sam correctly answered this question over on the Prismic Community: https://community.prismic.io/t/cannot-get-value-form-json-object-in-a-sveltekit-loop/6765/9